# How can I run a Kotlin workload asynchronously but without concurrency?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

I am working on a android app,

A service is running in foreground in an android app

This service is responsible for uploading image to S3

There's a camera activity where user can capture images

I need a logic to upload image one by one through service

Currently when user captures a image then there is a function call which uploads a image

The function call after each successful image capture is makimg images to upload concurrently

Can someone suggest a logic to upload images using a queue?

Comment: I think you answered yourself already - use a queue. If you use coroutines then create a `Channel` and start a coroutine that consumes its items. You can do the same without coroutines using `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: Sorry if i am making any mistake but, I understand that I can use queue but, after each insertion i need to run upload image function right? then again it will be a concurrent upload what is the use of queue

Comment: Is your image upload function asynchronous? If yes, then the easiest would be to redesign your code to make it synchronous. If it is based on callbacks right now and you want to keep it this way then you need to start new upload from the queue when the current upload finishes. This is a little more complicated than going synchronous, but still not that bad.

Comment: No image upload function is not asynchronous

Comment: Then why do you think it would upload concurrently? I think about something very simple like: `channel.consumeEach { upload(it) }`. It won't upload concurrently as long as `upload()` is synchronous.

Comment: Alright thanks will implement it that way